Simple javascript bookmarkerlet not working, clientside validation script causing error, how can I bypass
very grateful for any help.  I have a huge spreadsheet of data that I need to manually load into a web form https://www.elogbook.org/.  This will be very tedious, I looked at a few options and decided a javascript bookmarklet would help a lot to auto-populate the input fields in the web form.  This did seem to work well in terms of the fields getting filled in but for some reason the website I am loading data into doesnt recognise the fields that have been entered by the javascript and it triggers the client-side javascript validation to report an error.  here is a simplified example of the javascript
javascript: (() => {
  document.getElementById('patientid').value = "TESTTEST";
})();

This puts the value into the field nicely but the clientside javascript triggers an error as if not text has been entered??
Screenshot of error
You can see the text is in the field but the form thinks there is no text.  Any ideas why this is happening, it means my solution will not work as I will need to go through the entire form.  Is there a way to make the client side script recognize my text?  I am aware the elogbook website may be the problem but I have no control over this.  Is there a clever way using bookmarklet to turn-off or bypass the validation and post the form regardless?  Very grateful for help, am aware there may be a simple solution but I cant find it.
I used the document inspector in Chrome to look at the underlying html for the form control, it looks like this
Screenshot of document inspector
it seems to use angularJS which I am not familiar with at all, I tried various things to force the object to be valid and not untouched but still stuck.

Just want to clear that if you are putting the same id TESTTEST manually in the form, it works?

Thanks, yes if I use the form normally, i.e. I write in the form boxes manully, the form works fine, but it will take me a long time hence trying to fill the boxes with javascript

Can you share the form link, or can provide a reproducible example to test this?

this is the form link, https://client.elogbook.org/eLogbook/Operations/OperationMaintain/Add, the problem is its an authenticated website so need a user id and login, I am not sure how I can create a reproducible example of a website I didnt create, I appreciate it is difficult to help in that situation

You can try first focusing on the input then entering the value and blurring the field again and see if that works for you.

I had tried focus() and blur() but same problem sadly, it does provoke the error message though

Thanks for the help, triggering the change event seems to fix it, must be if form value changed by javascript doesnt trigger the chnge event


javascript: (() => {
  var el = document.getElementById('patientid');
  el.value = "TESTTEST";
  el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
})();



